# Can't use returned data from AngularJS Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I try to show some information in a table using http request.

For that I create a factory and I am calling that factory inside a controller. When I verify (with FireBug) if '$scope.showSal' have data, it tell me that it exists an array with 4 elements (totally good).

The problem is that doesn't show on screen any data.

With simple assignment like $scope.showSal = [{...}] it works, but when I use a factory it doesn't work.

May someone help me to use the received data from factory?

PS: For testing I am using a specific array to return and not returning the response.data (but even I return response.data it have the same behavior)

```
var app = angular.module("salariesApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.factory('salServ', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var showSal = {};

    showSal.getItems = function () {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/TT2/GetSalariesDetails')
            .then(
            function (response) {
                alert("OK");
                return [{ id: '1', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle Romania' },
                            { id: '2', an: '2016', den: 'Microsoft' },
                            { id: '3', an: '2016', den: 'Computer Generated Solutions - CGS Europe' },
                            { id: '4', an: '2016', den: 'IBM' }];
            },
            function (response) {
              alert("NO");
            }
          );
    };
    return showSal;
}]);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'salServ', function($scope, salServ) {    
    $scope.showSal = salServ.getItems();
    console.log($scope.showSal);

    $scope.showItems = $scope.showSal;
}]);
```

HTML code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Research project</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js" data-semver="3.0.0" data-require="jquery@*"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.7" data-require="angularjs@1.5.7"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js@*" data-semver="0.12.1" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-app="salariesApp">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-click="sortBy(id)">Nr. crt.</th>
          <th ng-click="sortBy(an)">Anul</th>
          <th ng-click="sortBy('den')">Denumirea institutiei/companiei</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="tableSearch"></td>
          <td class="tableSearch">
            <input type="text" ng-value="{{crrYear}}" ng-model="searchSal.an" id="inputYear" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td class="tableSearch">
            <input type="text" ng-model="searchSal.den" id="inputName" class="form-control" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="rows in showItems">
          <td class="spa-col-md-1">{{rows.id}}</td>
          <td class="spa-col-md-2">{{rows.an}}</td>
          <td class="col-md-5">{{rows.den}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http.get()` is **asynchronous** and returns a `Promise`. The HTTP call is certainly not completed when you try to set `$scope.showItems` value.

Try

```
var app = angular.module("salariesApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.factory('salServ', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var showSal = {};

    showSal.getItems = function (callBack) {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/TT2/GetSalariesDetails')
                .then(
                callBack (response.data),
                function (response) {
                    alert("NO");
                }
              );
    };
    return showSal;
}]);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'salServ', function ($scope, salServ) {
    salServ.getItems(
        function (data) {
            $scope.showItems = data;
            console.log($scope.showItems);//or $log...
        }
    );
}]);
```

Comment: @Doro I assume you know what your service returns. Anyway, the data should be located in response.data. See my edited answer

Comment: Yes, I known what is returning. Now it tell me that the 'response' is not defined...

Comment: @Doro Are you sure that your service returns something.  Replace `callBack (response.data)` by `callBack ([{ id: '1', an: '2016', den: 'Oracle Romania' },
                            { id: '2', an: '2016', den: 'Microsoft' },
                            { id: '3', an: '2016', den: 'Computer Generated Solutions - CGS Europe' },
                            { id: '4', an: '2016', den: 'IBM' }])`
...so you can test with your hard-coded value.

Comment: Thanks... This works... My bad that I had an extra attribute :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust console.log function in angular , because console browser can get information after loading. Use $log instead :)

You can add a ng-if on div contains based on your scope value like :

```
<table class="table" ng-if="showItems">
```

It generate the table only if have received items in showItems

Comment: I tried as you tell me, but the table it is showing but without any data.

Comment: delete your "alert" instruction and return false in fail callback function statement

Comment: It doesn't have any effect because the alert it stops the code until you click on the alert and then it will go forward... and even you specify return false in the second statement it will have the same behavior if all is ok...